# Create custom validator to check if the input is a string in Parsley

Tags: javascript, jquery, parsley.js

I want to create a custom validator that check if the input is a string and not a number. Example: I enter 2 in the input it should display the error message and it will be triggered when I put **data-parsley-name**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/parsley.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="f_name" name="f_name" placeholder="Enter First Name" data-parsley-required="true" data-parsley-trigger=" focusout" data-parsley-name>
```

```
window.Parsley.addValidator('name', {
        requirementType: 'string',
        validateString: function(value) {
            if(isNaN(value)){
                return value;
            }
        },
        messages: {
          en: 'Enter a Valid Name',

        }
      });
```

Answer (score 1):

I found out I can use **data-parsley-pattern="^[a-zA-Z]+$"**

Comment: Glad to see that you got the answer by yourself. Good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

In your validator function change this:

```
validateString: function(value) {
        if(value === "" + value){
            return value;
            console.log(this.messages.en);
        }
    }
```

But if you want to validate numbers use this code:  `if(Number(value) === value);`.

`Number(value)` is turning your value to the number. And if it is equal to your input it will return it and print the message.

Comment: still not working, I'm trying to validate if it is not a string.

Comment: still not working it still don't show the error message if I input number

Comment: I made an update for this too. But you can write whatever You want.

Comment: Okay, I create a function and call the message. You can reference to sibling properties in object with `this` statement. What about now?

Comment: still not working.. you can redo my code.. I think my point is if the input is number then it will show the message. does $.isNum() or isNaN() could work?

Comment: Okay, I get it what you want now. This version is shorter and readable than any other.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199767/discussion-between-robert-hovhannisyan-and-gio-garcia).

Comment: `value` is always going to be of type string, so  `(value === "" + value)` is always true

Comment: @ArleighHix and what if the value comes from another source? It's better to use this solution to be sure.

Comment: @RobertHovhannisyan it's coming from a specific source, the one being validated `input type="text"` where the value is always a string even if all characters are numerals `("123" === ""+"123")` evaluates to true

Comment: @ArleighHix okay I get it, Thank you, but the source problem was that he can't create a validator for string and I give him it.

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery's `.isNumeric()` https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.isNumeric/

```
    validateString: function(value) {
        if($.isNumeric(value) == false){
            return value;
        }
    }
```

Comment: @GioGarcia are you sure the validator is actually being triggered?